# how to design android app (webview) to fit different resolutions?

Tags: android, webview, screen

the android app will be made by webview.

there are many screen resolutions and the sides are in different ratio.
240x320 (3:4), 320x480 (2:3), 480x800 (3:5), 720x1280 (9:16)...

is it possible to..
- set the size of web page to be the largest one and left some space(but it doesn't seem to look good?) if the resolution of phone is smaller, then it "crop" the space to fit the screen(will it crops space or just display black space if it doesn't fit the size?)
 
- detect the type of phones and set the dimension, size of text, images

what is the best solution? 
thanks!

Comment: please read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) article.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of best practices from google. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html

The answer is formatting your page with the viewport meta tag. You can set the pixel density, and width among other properties.

Put this in your  and configure.

```
<meta name="viewport"
  content="
      height = [pixel_value | device-height] ,
      width = [pixel_value | device-width ] ,
      initial-scale = float_value ,
      minimum-scale = float_value ,
      maximum-scale = float_value ,
      user-scalable = [yes | no] ,
      target-densitydpi = [dpi_value | device-dpi |
                           high-dpi | medium-dpi | low-dpi]
      " />
```

Answer (score 0):

in android you can give your views some attributes for scratching and relative positioning. 
so in your case i would simply use a webview that would span all the screen. for that you can give the below attributes to your webview:

```
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

So I understand that your android app will have a single web view which will display content from some web url? Do you have control on the display/styling of the HTML page?

The support for multiple screen size should come from the HTML page displayed in the web view.
My suggestion is for example having 3 sets of CSS, for small/medium/large screen size respectively.

In Android we easily detect and classified the size and resolution of the device running the app. Then when your web view load the page, pass an extra param such as http://www.your-html-page.com?screen=large

[Supporting multiple screen size](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)